# A quick way to do find-file in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, editing

Every time I use find-file in Aquamacs or Emacs, it auto shows the previous directory, for example ~/Work/abc/cdf. However, if I want to open something from the ~ directory, I have to press Delete all the ways down to the first character. Is there any quick way to replace all the string with just one or two keys?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, while still in the mini buffer press Ctrl-A to go to the start of the file name path, and Ctrl-K to delete it to the end of the line, now your file path is empty and you can just type "~"

Answer (score 11):

No, you don't (have to press Delete).  Just type ~ and emacs will ignore everything before it.  Same with /.

Comment: Thanks, but without the package @Lindydancer has mentioned, I cannot do that in Aquamacs.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it works. It just does not delete the existing string so I thought it doesn't work out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, I learned something.  I've only used this on GNU Emacs, EmacsW32, XEmacs, and emacs23-nox. :)  **Edit** Okay, then yeah, you just have to look carefully.  On graphical modes, the color of the ignored string should be dimmed.  On terminal modes it actually surrounds the previous value with {} and you can return to it by backspacing.

Answer (score 1):

As harpo has already noted, just entering ~ will do the job for changing to home directory quickly. More generally, you can get a lot of improvements for quicker navigation in find-file by activating [ido-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings).

Answer (score 0):

how about `M-<DEL>` (backward-kill-word)

Should take one press per directory level

`C-x <DEL>` (backward-kill-sentence)

works but also wipes out the ~/

You can of course define your own commands and the emacs lisp to implement them.

As an alternate approach, many unixes will let you simply type a ~/ after the prefilled path and put your desired path after that, the ~/ overriding everything that came before.

Answer (score 0):

There are packages that does that for you, for example:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/minibuf-electric-gnuemacs.el

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun foo ()
  "Clear the minibuffer"
  (interactive)
  (delete-minibuffer-contents))

(define-key minibuffer-local-map [(meta ?k)] 'foo)
```