# Is there a shortcut to clear the "Find File:" buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to quickly clear the pre-filled text in the `Find File:` buffer (`C-x C-f`)? I find it's often annoying to `M-Backspace` each element out of the way, and `CMD-a` (on a mac) selects all the text in the buffer, including the `Find File:` text, which throws a `Text is read-only` error when hitting delete.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5125635/4525

Answer (score 13):

You can ignore the text if you do not want to edit it. If you start typing `/` (for full path) or `~` (for home), the default path gets gray and is ignored.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting to know. Doesn't seem to work with `tramp` though when I've ssh'd into another server and want to open a local file.

Comment: @unpluggd: Indeed, it does not work in some cases such as with `tramp-mode` or `url-handler-mode`.

Comment: In Emacs 26.1 for MacOS, C-S-Backspace doesn't do anything.  My guess would be that the line is already clear.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest <kbd>C-a C-k</kbd> (go to the beginning of the line and kill it - same as in OSX actually) or <kbd>C-S-backspace</kbd> (kill-whole-line).

Answer (score 1):

If you use ido, you won't need to use M-Backspace anymore (Backspace alone will do the same) and typing "~/" will directly take you to the home directory independently of the current path.

All you need is:

```
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode 'both) ;; for buffers and files
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to clear the text.

You can type the file name right after the pre-filled text:

```
C:/work/mydir/C:/temp/anotherdir
```

It works on Windows and on Unix as well.

Comment: I think you need a slash at the start of your replacement text: `C:/work/mydir/C:/temp/anotherdir` or `/home/login/mydir//tmp/anotherdir`